# Require small section of lodash to minimize size

Tags: node.js, browserify, lodash

I am using browserify on lodash and discovered that lodash made up a significant chunk of the browserified `bundled.js`.

I imported in the entire lodash but I mainly use the `cloneDeep` method so far.

```
var lodash = require('lodash');
```

How can I import only the necessary part of lodash to keep `bundled.js` small? I am using node.js v6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can cherry-pick just the `cloneDeep` method by `require('lodash/cloneDeep')`. There's also [babel-plugin-lodash](https://github.com/lodash/babel-plugin-lodash) to simplify cherry-picking and [lodash-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/lodash/lodash-webpack-plugin) for even smaller bundles.

Comment: Would [lodash.clonedeep](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.clonedeep) be enough?

Comment: Yes, lodash.clonedeep is enough

Comment: It is an honor to have the creator of lodash to answer my question. Upvoted. Correct answer but if you don't mind, I will select user8461258's answer as the answer because it applies to noob like me. I was indeed struggling with calling the lodash functions.

Answer (score 2):

⚠️ *Warning: "The per method standalone packages [will not be upgraded to v5](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/Roadmap#v500-2017)" - [John-David Dalton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40457214/require-small-section-of-lodash-to-minimize-size/40457468?noredirect=1#comment68269234_40457468)*

> - Discontinue [per method packages](https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/lodash-modularized) in favor of modular [lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash)

*If you're using lodash <= 4, continue reading.*

---

While [John-David Dalton's (lodash creator) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40457332/1218980) is on point, I'm making this an answer for future readers.

Every function of lodash is available as a module through npm. See [lodash-modularized](https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/lodash-modularized) for a complete list of available modules.

Like [lodash.clonedeep](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.clonedeep)

```
$ npm i --save lodash.clonedeep
```

That can be used like this:

```
var cloneDeep = require('lodash.clonedeep');
```

From the [lodash](https://lodash.com/) home page:

> ## Module Formats
>
> Lodash is available in a [variety of builds](https://lodash.com/custom-builds) & module formats.
>
> - [lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash) & [per method packages](https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/lodash-modularized)
> - [lodash-es](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash-es), [babel-plugin-lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-lodash), & [lodash-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash-webpack-plugin)
> - [lodash/fp](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/tree/4.16.4-npm/fp)
> - [lodash-amd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash-amd)

Comment: ⚠️ The per method standalone packages [will not be upgraded to v5](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/Roadmap).

Comment: @John-DavidDalton thanks, I made your comment into my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have been building up a package of simplified lodash functions that have a much smaller footprint. `cloneDeep` is one of them. You can check it out to see if it works for you: https://github.com/simontonsoftware/micro-dash

You can see [in the jsdocs](https://github.com/simontonsoftware/micro-dash/blob/master/lib/src/lang/clone-deep.ts#L7) that lodash's `cloneDeep`, when it is the only function you import, still pulls in `> 12K bytes` minified, whereas `micro-dash`'s version is `< 300 bytes`.

Just be aware of the differences listed in the readme. In the case of `cloneDeep`, the possibly relevant points are:

> - Only designed to work with primitives, plain objects, and arrays. It it not designed or tested to handle inherited properties, symbol keys, `arguments` objects, primitive objects (e.g. `Object(1)`), Dates, Maps, Sets, etc.
> - A modern environment/buildchain is assumed. E.g. this project will not contain duplicates of ES6 functions (such as `Array.isArray()`), and it may use ES6 functions directly. If you target older browsers/environments, you may need to include polyfills separately. However, it will only use features that can be polyfilled.

Answer (score 0):

Take note that there are differences when you call lodash functions depending on how you import lodash.

```
var lodash = require('lodash');
var clone = lodash.cloneDeep(obj);
```

If you do cherry-picking as John-David Dalton suggests, you need to call the function this way.

```
var lodash_clonedeep = require('lodash/cloneDeep');
var clone = lodash_clonedeep(obj);
```

The experts may overlook the possibility that newbies may not know the correct way to call the lodash functions.